# Who is pictured in this still from "X-Men: Days of Future Past"?

Tags: x-men, character-identification, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel

[image]

This frame was shown during the scene when Bishop and Kitty run in mutants' hideout. What are those pictures?

Comment: I should imagine that it's pictures brought in by the cast and crew. Or pictures that the studio has in its "general pictures" archive.

Comment: These are not pictures of mutations?
Perhaps mutations in the comics?

Comment: In the film these are clearly dead relatives and friends. Presumably some were mutants, while others are merely those who carry the Mutant-X gene that have been killed by the Sentinels preemptively.

Comment: it's clear
I ask who are they? what are their names?
Maybe it really just people, and maybe they are people he mutants we need to know,
It just intrigues me